# Hide price when product has class - javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a category with many products. But only one product has specific class. I need to search this class and hide price only for this product.

This code hide prices of all products:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if($('.flag').length > 0)
    $('.prices').hide();
});
```

This is a sample code of website:

```
<div class="products">
  <div class="product">
    <div class="flag">
  ...
    </div>
    <div class="prices">
  ...
    </div>

  <div class="product">
    <div class="flag2">
  ...
    </div>
    <div class="prices">
  ...
    </div>

  <div class="product">
    <div class="flag3">
  ...
    </div>
    <div class="prices">
  ...
    </div>

  <div class="product">
    <div class="flag4">
  ...
    </div>
    <div class="prices">
  ...
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks.

Comment: What is the issue? What doesn't work?

Comment: Can you provide what the html of your categories display looks like? jQuery can easily act on elements based on classes etc., but we don't have a way of knowing what that looks like to provide more help.

Comment: i add simple html of website

Comment: How do you mark the flags. Don't you think radio buttons would be better for marking the flag or do you prefer check boxes.

Answer (score -1):

If I'm not mistaken `$('.flag .prices').hide()` should work without any additional checks. If you would need to do anything else with this container just use

```
$('.flag').each((_, containerEl) => {
    //...your code where containerEl is your container element reference ...
})
```

But it won't work if you have some kind of lazy loading. It'll be a bit trickier.

Comment: yes, i need add "each" to the code, but i dont how :-/

Comment: Start with the each code I sent above and consider containerEl as i.e body element. So if you would like to remove `div` with class e.g `should-be-removed` the code should be like this: 
`$(containerEl).find('.should-be-removed').remove()` 
In the most common case it should work.

Answer (score -1):

I am guessing to a certain extend, but could it be that you want to hide the price for a product that has a `flagx` class assigned to it? (The following sample uses `x=3`).

If so, the following might help:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.flag3').next('div').hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="products">
  <div class="product">
    <div class="flag">
    flag
    </div>
    <div class="prices">
    prices for flag
    </div>

  <div class="product">
    <div class="flag2">
  flag2 div
    </div>
    <div class="prices">
  prices for flag2
    </div>

  <div class="product">
    <div class="flag3">
  flag3 div
    </div><div class="prices">
    prices for flag3
    </div>

  <div class="product">
    <div class="flag4">
    flag4
    </div>
    <div class="prices">
    prices for flag4
    </div>
</div>
```